# got error when initializing a class object in main() c++: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, class, constructor, instantiation

the class constructor declaration in .hpp:

```
physicsBody(float m, std::vector<float> verts, std::vector<float> initPos, std::vector<float> initVelo);
```

the class variable declaration in .hpp:

```
ParticleSystem body;
float mass;
std::vector<float> vertices;
std::vector<float> initialPos;
std::vector<float> initialVelo;
```

the class constructor implementation in .cpp:

```
physicsBody::physicsBody(float m,
                         std::vector<float> verts,
                         std::vector<float> initPos,
                         std::vector<float> initVelo):
mass{m}, vertices{verts}, initialPos{initPos}, initialVelo{initVelo}
{    
    build_body();
    
    // Gravity is enabled as defalut
    for (auto& particle : body.pSystem)     particle.force[1] = -GRAVITY * particle.m;
}
```

In Main():

```
    float mass {2.0}; // in kg
    std::vector<float> initialPos = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    std::vector<float> initialVel = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    std::vector<float> verts = ball.vertices;
    physicsBody myball(mass, verts, initialPos, initialVel);
```

When I build, it gives me this error:

"physicsBody::physicsBody(float, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
_main in main.o

After a few searches, the error can come from the class instantiation does not match the definition, or declaration does not match implementation. I have been scratching my head in the past a few hours. Cannot fix it! My head must have been stuck in the somewhere! Could someone please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: *When I build* How do you build?

Comment: what do you mean? command + B in xcode

Comment: TLDR of the duplicate, you need to compile and link all your files together. Looks like you are only compiling main.cpp, and not your other file.

Comment: Xcode generates a detailed build log when it builds your project.  It might be worth taking a look at that to see if it is compiling (and linking) all the files you expect it to.